# Using SelectionContainer inside BottomSheet doesn't show selection options

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my Jetpack compose project i display some text that i'd like to be selectable in a bottom sheet, the text is contained within SelectionContainer composable. the user is able to select the text but the issue is no options (copy, share, select all etc) are showing on selection.

i tried using the SelectionContainer elsewhere outside the bottomsheet and it functions without issues, why is that happening only with bottomsheet?

code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheet(
    showSheet: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    if (showSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
            sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
            dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary)
            ) {
                SelectionContainer {
                    Text(
                        text = "muh text",
                        color = Color.Black,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Right,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Image to simplify question
[image]

Comment: Can you please put the image of what exactly you want?

Comment: question edited above

Comment: I didn't work for me neither. ModalBottomSheet is still in experimental state, so I wouldn't expect it to be working well with other popups. Consider creating a "copy all" button and letting users to select the range using the system clipboard UI; or somehow try to catch a select callback and draw your own popup with actions.

Comment: i actually considered that (custom drawing my own menu) but i'm completely new to this sort of thing and have no idea where to start..tried finding any examples online but to no avail